# Google Flexible Environment Deploy Fail "Application startup error"

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-flexible

Trying to deploy to Google Cloud Flexible Environment but get `Application startup error`
Could someone explain this error?

```
 [INFO] GCLOUD: DONE
 [INFO] GCLOUD: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] GCLOUD:
 [INFO] GCLOUD: Updating service [default]...
 [INFO] GCLOUD: ..............................................................................................................failed.
 [INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
 [INFO] GCLOUD: Application startup error:
 [INFO] GCLOUD:    [Clear CT: 5.0 ms]
 [INFO] GCLOUD:    [Other: 13.2 ms]
 [INFO] GCLOUD:       [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
 [INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Proc: 12.6 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Enq: 0.2 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Redirty Cards: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Register: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Free CSet: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Eden: 109.0M(109.0M)->0.0B(123.0M) Survivors: 4096.0K->15.0M Heap: 114.4M(492.0M)->17.7M(492.0M)]
[INFO] GCLOUD:  [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.06 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2016-12-12T15:52:45.061+0000: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.0216334 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Parallel Time: 18.2 ms, GC Workers: 1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Start (ms):  4441.7]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ext Root Scanning (ms):  1.5]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Update RS (ms):  0.5]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Processed Buffers:  8]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Scan RS (ms):  1.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Code Root Scanning (ms):  0.6]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Object Copy (ms):  14.4]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Termination (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Termination Attempts:  1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Other (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Total (ms):  18.1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker End (ms):  4459.9]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Fixup: 0.2 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Clear CT: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Other: 3.3 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Proc: 2.9 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Enq: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Register: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Free CSet: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Eden: 9216.0K(9216.0K)->0.0B(118.0M) Survivors: 15.0M->3072.0K Heap: 26.7M(492.0M)->16.5M(492.0M)]
[INFO] GCLOUD:  [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2016-12-12T15:52:46.766+0000: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.0993228 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Parallel Time: 43.3 ms, GC Workers: 1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Start (ms):  6146.6]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ext Root Scanning (ms):  1.1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Update RS (ms):  2.3]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Processed Buffers:  18]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Scan RS (ms):  0.2]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Code Root Scanning (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Object Copy (ms):  39.7]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Termination (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Termination Attempts:  1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Other (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Total (ms):  43.3]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker End (ms):  6189.9]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Clear CT: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Other: 55.9 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Proc: 48.7 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Enq: 0.7 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Redirty Cards: 6.2 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Register: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Free CSet: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Eden: 118.0M(118.0M)->0.0B(54.0M) Survivors: 3072.0K->16.0M Heap: 134.5M(492.0M)->48.5M(492.0M)]
[INFO] GCLOUD:  [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.10 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2016-12-12T15:52:47.174+0000: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.0741297 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Parallel Time: 66.8 ms, GC Workers: 1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Start (ms):  6554.6]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ext Root Scanning (ms):  1.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Update RS (ms):  18.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Processed Buffers:  75]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Scan RS (ms):  2.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Code Root Scanning (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Object Copy (ms):  41.5]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Termination (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Termination Attempts:  1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Other (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Total (ms):  62.6]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker End (ms):  6617.2]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Clear CT: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Other: 7.2 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Proc: 6.7 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Enq: 0.2 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Register: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Free CSet: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Eden: 29.0M(20.0M)->0.0B(73.0M) Survivors: 16.0M->5120.0K Heap: 77.5M(492.0M)->57.0M(492.0M)]
[INFO] GCLOUD:  [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.07 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2016-12-12T15:52:47.920+0000: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.0377450 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Parallel Time: 25.0 ms, GC Workers: 1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Start (ms):  7300.7]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ext Root Scanning (ms):  1.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Update RS (ms):  2.7]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Processed Buffers:  17]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Scan RS (ms):  3.9]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Code Root Scanning (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Object Copy (ms):  17.4]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Termination (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Termination Attempts:  1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Other (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Total (ms):  25.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker End (ms):  7325.7]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Clear CT: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Other: 12.7 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Proc: 11.9 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Enq: 0.4 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Register: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Free CSet: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Eden: 61.0M(61.0M)->0.0B(69.0M) Survivors: 5120.0K->9216.0K Heap: 118.0M(492.0M)->76.5M(492.0M)]
[INFO] GCLOUD:  [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2016-12-12T15:52:48.461+0000: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.0487689 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Parallel Time: 29.1 ms, GC Workers: 1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Start (ms):  7842.3]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ext Root Scanning (ms):  1.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Update RS (ms):  2.3]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Processed Buffers:  14]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Scan RS (ms):  4.5]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Code Root Scanning (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Object Copy (ms):  21.2]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Termination (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Termination Attempts:  1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Other (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Total (ms):  29.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker End (ms):  7871.3]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Clear CT: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Other: 19.6 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Proc: 18.9 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Enq: 0.3 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Register: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Free CSet: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Eden: 47.0M(47.0M)->0.0B(110.0M) Survivors: 9216.0K->7168.0K Heap: 123.5M(492.0M)->91.5M(492.0M)]
[INFO] GCLOUD:  [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2016-12-12T15:52:49.418+0000: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.1005872 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Parallel Time: 50.7 ms, GC Workers: 1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Start (ms):  8798.8]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ext Root Scanning (ms):  0.9]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Update RS (ms):  3.3]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Processed Buffers:  21]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Scan RS (ms):  2.4]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Code Root Scanning (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Object Copy (ms):  35.9]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Termination (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Termination Attempts:  1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Other (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Total (ms):  42.6]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker End (ms):  8841.3]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Clear CT: 2.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Other: 47.8 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Proc: 46.8 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Enq: 0.5 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Register: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Free CSet: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Eden: 93.0M(93.0M)->0.0B(88.0M) Survivors: 7168.0K->13.0M Heap: 184.5M(492.0M)->117.0M(492.0M)]
[INFO] GCLOUD:  [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.10 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2016-12-12T15:52:50.198+0000: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.0774613 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Parallel Time: 65.8 ms, GC Workers: 1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Start (ms):  9578.7]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ext Root Scanning (ms):  1.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Update RS (ms):  3.8]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Processed Buffers:  17]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Scan RS (ms):  8.7]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Code Root Scanning (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Object Copy (ms):  52.1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Termination (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:          [Termination Attempts:  1]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Other (ms):  0.0]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker Total (ms):  65.7]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [GC Worker End (ms):  9644.4]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Clear CT: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Other: 11.6 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Proc: 10.9 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Ref Enq: 0.3 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Register: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:       [Free CSet: 0.1 ms]
[INFO] GCLOUD:    [Eden: 47.0M(47.0M)->0.0B(133.0M) Survivors: 13.0M->8192.0K Heap: 164.0M(492.0M)->131.0M(492.0M)]
[INFO] GCLOUD:  [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.08 secs]
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:03 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-12T16:53:01+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/508M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (default-cli) on project XXX: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: I have the same error and still could not find the reason, sometimes it succeeds, but most of the time deployment fails. Exception stack trace has nothing useful in it.

Comment: 1. How long does your app take to initialize? There is timeouts for various part of init, overall  25 minutes by default.

2. If the app even began to initialize, you will see something at Stackdriver Log Viewer. What does it show?